# how to override react-bootstrap with custom css file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack, react-bootstrap

I use `react-bootstrap`, but I want to modify some of the elements, so I wrote my own `custom.css`. However it doesn't make any changes (only when I put `!important`, but the file is so large so it's not a good option).

```
import {MenuItem, Nav, Navbar, NavBrand, NavDropdown, NavItem} from "react-bootstrap";
import {LinkContainer, MenuItemLink} from "react-router-bootstrap";
import '../assets/css/custom.css';
```

This is what I did so far.

Comment: First of all make sure you're loading your *custom.css* after that `react` plugins CSS and also use proper `selector` , of doing these you won't have to use `!important`.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay what do you mean by after? i import in the following order.

Comment: then may be its selector issue

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay but i am also modifying classes, .navbar i.e

Answer (score 6):

When are you importing the Bootstrap CSS? I have an app which successfully uses Bootstrap with some overrides, which does this at the top of its `index.js`:

```
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
require('./bootstrap-overrides.css')
```